# How to make repeating textblocks in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

Databinding still confues me and I am not sure how to essential make these controls repeat for each bound piece of data I have.

```
   <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="this is a header"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,36,0,0" Name="txt" Text="line under the header" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBlock Height="30" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,9,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="530" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" />
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="305,42,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" />
            </Grid>
```

[image]

If my data source would have a count of 50. I would expect to see 50 of these groupings(I probably need to get a scroll bar though).

Not sure how to do this though. I need some sort of datatemplate I guess? Also "line under the header" should be clickable and highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the control named "ItemsControl". Not a derived class, not a ListBox, just plain simple `ItemsControl`.

Either in code or in XAML, you set the ItemsControl's `ItemsSource` property to any collection containing your items.

In XAML (either in VS or Blend, to do it WYSIWYG in Blend you must somehow provide design data) you set the ItemsControl's `ItemTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` that contains the XAML subtree you want to repeat for every item in your collection.

Inside the `DataTemplate`, replace "line under the header" with the Button control, with `Content="line under the header"`, and style it however you want. Then, add `CallMethodAction` to your button. It only takes 2 clicks in Blend, the first one is on "Assets" window. Specify `TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="actSubtitleClicked"`. This way, the framework will call the `void actSubtitleClicked()` method of the item where user clicked the "line under the header".

For best performance, you should also modify the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel template, replacing StackPanel with VirtualizingStackPanel (again, a few clicks in Blend, the first one is the right click, then "Edit additional templates / ItemsPanel / Edit a copy")